# Three digit number $ABC$ with $ABC = A + B^2 + C^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Is there a trick for solving this problem about number of digits?

> $ABC$ is a three-digit natural number, such that $ABC = A + B^2 + C^3$.
>
> According to above equation what is $ABC$ ?

Comment: I suppose the equation is wrong, because $ABC$ means $A\times B \times C$. The first trick is to write $$100A+10B+C=A+B^2+C^3$$

Comment: You get four possibilities for $A, B, C$, no obvious trick though...

Comment: Cannot I solve this problem without trying their possibilities ?

Comment: @Macavity What are the solutions?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt $ABC \in \{ 135, 175, 518, 598 \}$

Comment: @Macavity How did you find them ? Can you explain ?

Comment: @sinanakyazici searching down from $C=9$ makes it less exhaustive. You can then fix $A$, then see if there is a $B$ possible.  Though not very elegant.

Comment: There has to be a solution that is not trial & error.

Comment: @Auberon, why??

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, I'm trying to say that it might be possible to solve said equation without trial & error (I'd like to consider trial & error a bad math practice unless considered the only possible method). Starting from miracle173's comment, you can solve the equation by finding the zero points of a function with three variables. Using lineair algebra, you know that the equation has a infinite possible answers. Of course we're trying to find a subset of these numbers using given restrictions. Unfortunately, I'm no grandmaster in this field.

Comment: @Auberon, "I'm trying to say that it might be possible to solve said equation without trial & error" but what you actually wrote was very different: "There has to be a solution that is not trial & error." And linear algebra does not apply, as the equation is not linear.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, I see. Then at least one should proof that the set proposed by PeterWoolfitt is correct and complete.

Comment: @Auberon Not me! It was Macavity who gave the solution set.

Comment: Sorry I'm blind and ruining the comments here.

Answer (score 4):

The following is not really a trick, but at least it's a computation which can be done by hand.

First note that $10B\ge B^2$ (since $0\le B\le9$). Hence 
$$100A+10B+C=A+B^2+C^3\implies 99A+C<C^3$$
and since $A\ge1$, this gives us immediately that $C\ge5$.

Now, assume that $B=0$. Then we have $100A+C=A+C^3$, but since none of $5^3=125$, $6^3=216$, $7^3=343$, $8^3=512$, and $9^3=729$ are in the range $[100n-10,100n+10]$, there are no solutions with $B=0$, so from here on we assume $B\ne 0$

Now we have $10B>B^2+A$, so $100A<C^3$, and thus $A$ is at most the first digit of $C^3$, but since we also know $A$ must be at least the first digit of $C^3$ (easy to see from the original formulation of the problem), we have that $A$ is exactly the first digit of $C^3$.

Now all we have to do is solve $5$ quadratic equations for $B$ (one for each possible value of $C$) and see if there are integer solutions:

$C=5$:$$100+10B+5=1+B^2+125\implies B=3,7$$
$C=6$:$$200+10B+6=2+B^2+216\implies B=5\pm\sqrt{13}$$
$C=7$:$$300+10B+7=3+B^2+343\implies B=5\pm i\sqrt{14}$$
$C=8$:$$500+10B+8=5+B^2+512\implies B=1,9$$
$C=9$:$$700+10B+9=7+B^2+729\implies B=5\pm i\sqrt{2}$$

At long last this gives us the $4$ solutions $ABC\in\{135,175,518,598\}$.

Answer (score 4):

We are searching for numbers $A,B,C \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ that satisfy
$$100A+10B+C=A+B^2+C^3 \tag{1}$$
We can find the solution by checking all $1000$ possible tuples but I will try to shrink the number of tuples we have to check. We transform $(1)$ to
$$99A+B(10-B)+C-C^3=0 \tag{2}$$
From this we get
$$B(10-B) \equiv C^3-C \pmod {99} \tag{3}$$
We calculate the possible values for B and C

$$\tag{4}\begin{array}{r|r}
B &B(10-B)\\
\hline
0&0\\
1&9\\
2&16\\
3&21\\
4&24\\
5&25\\
6&24\\
7&21\\
8&16\\
9&9
\end{array}
$$

$$\tag{5}\begin{array}{r|r|r}
C &C^3-C&C^3-C \mod {99}\\
\hline{}
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
2&6&6\\
3&24&24\\
4&60&60\\
5&120&21\\
6&210&12\\
7&336&39\\
8&504&9\\
9&720&27\\
\end{array}
$$

Now we check which values of $B$ can be paired with values of $C$ because 
$$(B(10-B)) \mod 99 = (C^3-C) \mod 99$$
For $B$ the values of $B(10-B)$ and $B(10-B) \mod{99}$ are the same.

$$\tag{6}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
B&C&C^3-C\\
\hline
0&0,1&0\\
1,9&8&504\\
3,7&5&120\\
4,6&3&24
\end{array}$$

We analyze $(2)$ $\pmod{2}$. We have
$$C^3-C \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$
$$B(10-B) \equiv B \pmod{2}$$
$$99A \equiv A\pmod{2}$$
and therefore
$$A \equiv B \pmod{2}$$
so the possible values can be reduced to

$$\tag{7}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
B&C&A\\
\hline
0&0,1&0,2,4,6,8\\
1,9&8&1,3,5,7,9\\
3,7&5&1,3,5,7,9\\
4,6&3&0,2,4,6,8
\end{array}$$

From $(5)$ we see that all possible values of $C^3-C$ are multiples of 24 so we can analyze $(2)$ $\pmod{24}$ and get

$$3A+B(10-B)=0 \pmod{24} \tag{8}$$

so $(7)$ can be reduced further to

$$\tag{9}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
A&B&C\\
\hline
0,8&0&0,1\\
5&1,9&8\\
1,9&3,7&5\\
0,8&4,6&3
\end{array}$$

Now we can check this $14$ possibilities or  we estimate the size of some digits similar to   @Peter Woolfitt's answer. From table $(4)$ we conclude that the minimum of $B(10-B)$ is $0$ and so from $(2)$ we get

$$99A \lt C^3-C \tag{10}$$

and further with the maximum of $C^3-C$ from table $(5)$
$$99A \le 720 $$
$$ A \le \frac{720}{99}=7^3/_{11}$$
$$A \le 7 \tag{11}$$

If we assume that $A \ge 1$ then from $(19)$ we get 
$$99 \lt C^3-C \tag{12}$$
and so
$$C \ge 5  \tag{13} $$

So from table $(9)$ the following remains

$$\tag{14}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
A&B&C\\
\hline
5&1,9&8\\
1&3,7&5
\end{array}$$

Now you only have to check that these are valid solutions.

If we allow for $A$ the digit $0$ then we cannot establish $(12)$ and $(13)$.

But if $A=0$ we get from $(2)$ the equation 
$$B(10-B)=C^3-C \tag{15}$$

and by comparing the values of $(4)$ and $(5)$

$$\tag{17}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
A&B&C\\
\hline
0&0&0,1\\
0&4,6&3
\end{array}$$

All the possible combinations from $(14)$ and $(17)$ satisfy $(1)$, so we get the following solutions:
$$
518\\
598\\
135\\
175
$$
Solutions with trailing zeros (and therefore these are not three digit numbers):
$$
000\\
001\\
043\\
063
$$

---

Of course the solution can be easily calculated by a [Python program](http://ideone.com/UZiyOn):

```
for A in range(10):
    for B in range(10):
        for C in range(10):
            if 100*A+10*B+C==A+B**2+C**3:
                print(100*A+10*B+C)
```